# Validate uniqueness of combination of multiple fields of a model in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

How to ensure uniqueness of a combination of multiple fields in loopback model. Like below is the model Organisation, I have two field name and contact in it, I want the combination of these two fields to be unique in the database.
For example :- while creating an organisation two records can have same value in the **'name'** field but the combination of the value of the  **'name'** and the **'contact'** field should be unique for each record in order to create it.

```
`{
  "name": "Organisation",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "contact": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use indexes for this purpose. Check [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Indexes), there are several very good examples that covers this topic.

```
"nameContactUniqueIndex": {
  "keys": {
     "name": 1,
     "contact": -1
   },
   "options": {
     "unique": true
   }
}
```

> A key value of 1 specifies ascending order, and -1 specifies descending order.

Comment: That helped. Can we customize the error message for the unique index in loopback?